# Scrapy Crawl Text after <div>

Tags: html, css, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl the following HTML code using Scrapy:

```
<td class="xyz"> 
   <div>Irrelevant</div>
   I want to get this text! 
</td>
```

How can I extract that text?

```
response.css('td.xyz::text').extract()
```

returns ' '

Answer (score 3):

Even when the extra `div` exists or not, you can do this to get the text you want

```
response.css('td.xyz::text').extract()[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But: Why? :) I Do not understand it...

Answer (score 1):

```
response.xpath('//td[@class="xyz"]/text()[2]').extract_first()
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Unfortunately, sometimes this extra <div> exists, sometimes it doesn't. How can I get the text all the time? Will your command still work?

Comment: @pmax1 No but you can use another approach: get whole `<td>` element, next remove ALL irrelevant elements from it (using `lxml` and `.remove()` )

Comment: May be `response.xpath('//td[@class="xyz"]/text()').extract()`will work for you